# XStream marshal XML string

Tags: java, xml, xstream

In my project, I use the XStream library for de-serialize and serialize XML file. In this files, some task contains an XML string that doesn't need to parse.

For do that, I redefine the unmarshal and marshal methods of XStream.Converter but I have a little problem with the marshal result.
My marshal method:

```
public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    writer.setValue(value.toString());
}
```

When I try to get the string (example of value.toString())

```
<echo>Hi</echo>
<echo>stackoverflow</echo>
```

I obtain the result:

```
&lt;echo>Hi&lt;/echo>
&lt;echo>stackoverflow&lt;/echo>
```

How I can obtain the right string??

Comment: I'm confused why the left brackets are encoded, but not the right side...

Comment: Me too... examining in debug, i found that BufferingXmlWriter change the character **< > &** to **&lt; &amp; &gt;** . But **<** is change only if the previous character is **]**.